# Mat-Error Required validation error message shows when form is first open

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a custom control component that is used to show a required validation error for mat-chip-lists. On the form that I'm using this component, when I first open this form the required validation message shows. I only want it to show when the field is not populated with any data. Can someone please provide a reason why and a solution to what I need to do to get the validation to work properly.

I could be overcomplicating this and it's much simpler than I thought.

**html where mat-error element for required show:**

```
<mat-form-field [floatLabel]="floatLabel">
 <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
  <mat-chip-list #optionList aria-label="label" required>
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of selectedOptions" (removed)="removed(item)" 
 [removable]="!item.disabled" [disabled]="item.disabled">
  {{ item.text }}
  <mat-icon *ngIf="!item.disabled" matChipRemove>cancel</mat-icon>
</mat-chip>
  <input
  #optionInput
  type="text"
  [placeholder]="placeholder"
  [formControl]="formControl"
  [matAutocomplete]="optionAutoComplete"
  [matChipInputFor]="optionList"
  [required]="required"
  />
</mat-chip-list>
<mat-autocomplete #optionAutoComplete="matAutocomplete" 
 (optionSelected)="selected($event.option.value)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
  {{ option.text }}
  </mat-option>
 </mat-autocomplete>
 <mat-hint *ngIf="hint">{{ hint }}</mat-hint>
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-error *ngIf="required === true && hasValue === false && 
        isInitialized === true"> {{ label }} is 
 <strong>required</strong> </mat-error>
```

**Typescript for the custom control**
The removed function fires when you remove selected items from the list. It turns the check back on and sends the update to the parent component.

```
 Component({
  selector: 'app-chips',
  templateUrl: './chips.component.html',
 })
 export class ChipsComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() label = '';
  @Input() placeholder = '';
  @Input() options: Options[] = [];
  @Input() selectedOptions: Options[] = [];
  @Input() floatLabel: FloatLabelType = 'auto';
  @Input() hint!: string | undefined;
  @Input() required = true;
  hasValue: boolean = this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
  isInitialized: boolean | undefined;

 @ViewChild('optionInput') optionInput: ElementRef | undefined;

 @Output() onRemoved = new EventEmitter<Options>();
 @Output() selectedOptionsChanged = new EventEmitter<Options[]>();

formControl = new FormControl('');
filteredOptions: Observable<Options[]> | undefined;

iterableDiffer: IterableDiffer<Options>;

constructor(private readonly iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers) {
   this.iterableDiffer = this.iterableDiffers.find([]).create();
 }

 ngDoCheck(): void {
  const optionChanges = this.iterableDiffer.diff(this.options);
   if (optionChanges) {
    this.filteredOptions = of(this.options);
   }
   if (this.required === undefined) {
    this.required = false;
   }
 }

 ngOnInit(): void {
   this.subscribeFilterOptions();
   this.isInitialized = true;
}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
     this.isInitialized = true;
     }

 selected(value: Options): void {
  if (this.optionInput) {
    this.optionInput.nativeElement.value = '';
   }
   if (!this.selectedOptions.find((x) => x.text === value.text)) {
    this.selectedOptions.push(value);
    this.selectedOptionsChanged.emit(this.selectedOptions);
  }
  this.hasValue = this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
}

private subscribeFilterOptions() {
  this.filteredOptions = this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map((value: string | Options) =>
    value && typeof value === 'string' ? this.options.filter((o) => 
 o.text.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) : 
this.options.slice()
   )
  );
}
removed(value: Options): void {
  this.onRemoved.emit(value);
  this.hasValue = this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
  }
 }
```

**Mat-chip-list component on the form**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <app-linq-chips
    label="Entities"
    placeholder="Add Entity..."
    [options]="entityOptions"
    [selectedOptions]="selectedEntities"
    [hint]="
      entityListHasDisabledOptions === true
        ? 'Please remove this contact from any roles for an entity prior to removing their 
     association to that entity.'
        : undefined
    "
    (onRemoved)="removeEntity($event)"
  >
  </app-linq-chips>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `hasValue` is only set when a chip is selected or removed. When the component is initialized it's value is false as the number of selected options is zero.

```
hasValue: boolean = this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
```

The `required` variable is initialized to true, so the mat error condition below:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="required === true && hasValue === false"> {{ label }} is 
 <strong>required</strong> </mat-error>
```

will be true, so the error will show initially.

To fix this issue, add an extra boolean variable, `isInitialized` (or whatever you want to name it), set it to false in the ngOnInit(), then set it to true in the ngAfterViewinit().

Update your `mat-error` condition like follows:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="required === true && hasValue === false && isInitialized === true"> {{ label }} is 
 <strong>required</strong> </mat-error>
```

Try the above and it should only error check after the component selections are made.

Comment: Hi @Andrew Halil, I updated to the changes you suggested and the required message still shows when the form is initially open. I also updated the cod my original post to show the changes you suggested. Please review to make sure it looks correct and if it does what other things can I try since this didn't work. Thanks